# Foreign Luxembourg resident with passport less than 6 months validity

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, passports, paperwork, luxembourg

I am not sure if this was asked already.

I am researching for passport validity for Schengen for non-EU long term residents but I cant find any answer.

My passport will expire on May 2019 and I am currently on holiday outside of EU and returning to Luxembourg on Jan 2019. I understand that passport should have a validity at least 3 months from the departure date. I have a long term resident status and my residence permit is still valid for at least 3 years.

Will I have an issue to enter the Schengen area?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the 3-month rule only applies to visitors to the Schengen area. Since you have a residence permit, your passport and residence permit only need to be valid on the day you re-enter the EU.

This is the information all check-in agents will see as well. Specifically.

> - Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be
>     valid for a minimum of 3 months beyond the period of
>     intended stay.
>
>   - Passports and other documents accepted for entry issued to
>       **residents** of Andorra, Monaco, San Marino, Vatican City
>       (Holy See) and **Schengen Member States** must be
>       **valid on arrival**.

Comment: I was just going to post an answer nearly identical to this, but then thought to check the [Schengen Borders Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02016R0399-20170407) first.  The code makes no exception for those with a long-stay visa or residence permit.  This is of course absurd, since the intended date of departure for such a person is frequently not definite. The only way I can make sense of that is to consider that someone with such a permit need not have an intended date of departure, but it seems like there ought to be an explicit provision for such people.

Comment: If you could include an example of the "the information all check-in agents will see" in this regard, it would improve the answer.

Comment: @phoog Practice isn't always consistent with law, but fine, I'll copy-paste the TIMATIC extract

Comment: Thanks.  *Law* is indeed not always consistent with law, in that the requirements imposed by the legal system may take into account elements of interpretation that are not obvious from the text of the act or even conflicting provisions that are expressed in an entirely separate act.

Comment: @phoog: Where do you find that? I see the three-months requirement in 6(1)(a)(i), but the entire 6(1) is (by its initial sentence) only about short visits. Holders of residence permits are explicitly allowed to miss some of the conditions in 6(1), by the exception in 6(5)(a).

Comment: @HenningMakholm thanks, I knew I'd overlooked something.  I suppose the code is silent on the subject of entry conditions for third-country nationals for intended stays exceeding the 90/180 rule because that is left to national law.  But that is also bizarre, since such people will frequently be entering the Schengen area through a country other than the country that issued the long-stay visa or residence permit.

Comment: @phoog: I would say that is 6(5)(a).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Oh I see what you mean.

Comment: `This is the information all check-in agents will see as well.` Where is this sourced from?

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk The database used by most check-in companies worldwide